# IllegalAnnotationsException while passing argument CommonsMultipartFile to webmethod uploadXLS in webservice file upload

Tags: java, spring, web-services

my web service code i am creating web service using Spring
please help i am getting IllegalAnnotationsException while passing argument CommonsMultipartFile to webmethod uploadXLS in webservice file upload

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;  
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
//Service Implementation Bean
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

public interface IncomeServer {
    @WebMethod String uploadXLS(CommonsMultipartFile uploadItem,String    remark,long custId) throws Exception;
```

}

getting following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1585)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:98)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:223)
... 27 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:171)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:99)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:250)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:205)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:513)
at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:333)
at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:45)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:121)
... 31 more
 Caused by:java.security.PrivilegedActionException:com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
        org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at      com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:158)
... 39 more
```

my ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
   xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">
 <wss:binding url="/hello">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#IncomeServer"/>
    </wss:service>
 </wss:binding>

  <!-- Web service methods -->
  <!--  <bean id="helloWs" class="trial.IncomeServer">
    <property name="helloWorldBo" ref="HelloWorldBo" />
  </bean> -->
<bean id="IncomeServer" class="trial.IncomeServerImpl" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Why do you expect a plain `JAX-WS` webserivce to understand what to do with a spring class?

Comment: Could you please post your `applicationContext.xml` File?

Comment: @user2004685  i have modified it

Comment: @NehaGarg I haven't made any changes. As per the logs the bean creation fails while setting the bean reference `IncomeServer` to property `service`